# How would I remove each Item after clicking the button next to it using plain Java script

Tags: javascript, arraylist, htmlcollection

Below is the html code

```
 <ul>
        <li>Item 1<button class="btn">click</button></li>
        <li>Item 2<button class="btn">click</button></li>
        <li>Item 3<button class="btn">click</button></li>
        <li>Item 4<button class="btn">click</button></li>
        <li>Item 5<button class="btn">click</button></li>
 </ul>

Below is JS code

var ul=document.querySelector("ul");
var li= document.querySelector("li");
var button= document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

button.forEach(function(i){
    i.onclick=function(){
        ul.removeChild(li);
    }
})
```

and the above code only removes the first item. I really do not know how to implement this one. Really confused on the html collections and node list concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the handler, select the button's `parentElement` and `remove()` it:

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

button.forEach(function(button) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    button.parentElement.remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 2<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 3<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 4<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 5<button class="btn">click</button></li>
</ul>
```

You could also use event delegation instead, if you wanted, rather than adding multiple listeners:

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.className === 'btn') {
    target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 2<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 3<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 4<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 5<button class="btn">click</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well thank you , I wasn't aware there is any remove method available. All I got was removeChild method only. Do you have any reference to it so I can further read through it

Comment: See [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Comment: So we can just select the parent element and use remove method directly?

Comment: The code works fine for me, is this method new because there were no example in w3c there was only to remove the child nodes

Comment: You can look at the MDN page to see how much it's supported - it's pretty old, but it's not supported on (ancient) IE. But that's what polyfills are for. (You can see a polyfill on the linked page.) Or, you can select the parent and then use `removeChild` if you wanted, it's up to you

Comment: Just out of curiosity if I want to use removeChild here. So the code would be button.parentElement.removeChild(li) ?

Comment: You want to remove the `li`, so you'd have to select the `ul`: `button.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(button.parentElement)`. Ugly-ish

Comment: On Great! Thank you so much now I understood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189801/discussion-between-jslearner-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the button and add event to it , that on `click` it will find its parent and will remove it

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.remove()
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 2<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 3<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 4<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 5<button class="btn">click</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove only next element .Use with 
[`this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.remove()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp)

**or**

else with same element remove  use [`this.parentElement.remove()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp)

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelector("li");
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

button.forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click',function() {
    this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 2<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 3<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 4<button class="btn">click</button></li>
  <li>Item 5<button class="btn">click</button></li>
</ul>
```